# Svelte with Babel for IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, babeljs, rollup, svelte

I'm using svelte with Rollup. And I need to support IE11

My current babel config in rollup.config.js is:

```
babel({
            extensions: [ '.js', '.mjs', '.html', '.svelte' ],
            exclude: 'node_modules/**',
            presets: [
                [
                '@babel/env',
                {
                    modules: 'false',
                    targets: {
                    browsers: '> 1%, IE 11, not op_mini all, not dead',
                    node: 8
                    },
                    useBuiltIns: 'usage'
                }
                ]
            ]
        }),
```

Please help me with configuring, now my app breaks both at IE and others(Chrome,Mozilla).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the configuration for the Babel plugin that is used [in Sapper](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template/blob/4e0face1bb1988c7a14668798b6258e3514409ae/rollup.config.js#L37) as a reference:

```js
babel({
  extensions: ['.js', '.mjs', '.html', '.svelte'],
  runtimeHelpers: true,
  exclude: ['node_modules/@babel/**'], // <= /!\ NOT 'node_mobules/**'
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {
      // adapter to ensure IE 11 support
      targets: '> 0.25%, not dead, IE 11'
    }]
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', {
      useESModules: true
    }]
  ]
}),
```

The important thing to note is that you can't exclude your whole `node_modules` from processing by Babel. The reason is that Svelte's code itself (i.e. under `node_modules/svelte`) needs to be transpiled for IE 11 support. Similarly, if you use third-party Svelte components, they will probably live under `node_modules`, yet require transpilation.

Another tricky bit to know is that transpiled code cannot be compatible with non transpiled code. In particular, ES6+ classes (that are used for Svelte components) are not compatible with their ES5 transpiled counterparts ("can't extend from non class, yada yada..."). So you will have to make sure that all your Svelte code is either transpiled with the same rules, or not transpiled at all...

Here's [another example](https://github.com/rixo/svelte-template-hot/blob/a750d8e18e8f537602014cc1a40a3d1741ed3716/rollup.config.js#L66) that uses (almost) the same config in a raw Svelte (i.e. non-Sapper) project.

Both links point to template projects, so you can easily clone & run them to try it for yourself. (If you want to use the second example, please notice that my link does not point to the master branch, so you'll have to checkout the right branch to try the babel config.)

Comment: Tried both. the result code changed, but the generated bundle is now invalid: ReferenceError: _classCallCheck is not defined

Comment: solved with npm install --save @babel/runtime. got another: Promise is undefined.

Comment: You'll need to bring your own polyfills (for Promise, and also Map and Set, possibly a couple of others) - https://polyfill.io

Comment: @RichHarris can you please give me an example of adding polyfills in rollup?

Comment: Don't do it in Rollup. Add a `<script>` tag pointing to polyfills.io. It will conditionally deliver the polyfills needed for the user's browser

Comment: [code example with polyfills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59374688/function-prototype-tostring-issues-in-ie11-svelte-babel-rollup)